# VS2015 now error C4477 "fprintf"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Until now, VS compile my code perfectly, but now VS2015 show me a warning that I can't to understand.

My code:

```
 CString nombre=_T("Stack"), dsc=_T("overflow");
  _ftprintf(file, _T("%s %s);\n"), nombre, m_dsc);
```

and VS2015:

> Warning   C4477   'fwprintf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of
>   type 'wchar_t *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'CString'

Why?, Why can't I use CString instead of wchart_t?. I want to use CString

Many thanks in advance

Josemi

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288.aspx - googled in 5 seconds.

Comment: Try to avoid using C vararg functions (like the whole `printf` and `scanf` families) in C++. Few, if any, compilers will be able to get the objects rights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I preffer GetString() instead of C-style casting:

```
_ftprintf(file, _T("%s %s);\n"), nombre.GetString(), dsc.GetString());
```

And I recommend to consider to use std::fstream's to work with text files.

Answer (score 6):

```
_ftprintf(file, _T("%s %s);\n"), (LPCTSTR)nombre, (LPCTSTR)dsc);
```

Comment: Yes. Now yes. The solution was simple. :-). Many thanks for your rapid answer

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <tchar.h>
// printf("%s %d %p", str, i, ptr);
_tprintf_s(_T("%s %d %p"), str, i, ptr);
```